# Adding OSMC to my SC card without destroying my loaded Raspbian OS

Tags: noobs, osmc

I reinstalled Raspbian OS many times trying to get the OpenCV libraries up and running. Now I'd like to add OSMC in a seperate partition without lossing the Raspian partition and the previously added programs and libraries.
I have downloaded a partition editor I've used before, GPARTED, to look at it's docs.  So... before I start...
Can NOOBS add a new OS non-destructfully?  Is GPARTED  suitable for shrinking and adding partitions?  If I use it,how can I download the entire OSMC OS?

Comment: you are trying to multi-boot the RPi ... why not just use a different SD card? ... also check this out http://www.multibootpi.com/

Comment: If you want to add a partition, be aware of this [problem with adding third partition](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78291/79866).

Answer (score 1):

`NOOBS` cannot add new OS, although [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) may be able to (with some work).

Frankly, why bother with `OSMC` just install `Kodi` in Raspbian.