# Partition of raspberry pi on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, ubuntu, backup, partition

When I booted raspbian on raspberry pi, the name of partition is

/dev/mmcblk0

But when I connect sd card via USB reader on Ubuntu 16.04, it shows a different name as

/dev/sdc

These sd cards are same. So what happened here?

And also does this matter when I backup and separate as two partitions with the different name by using

dd and fdisk commend ?

Comment: What happened is USB card reader having a different name than a native SD/MMC reader in Linux. Why did you expect them to be the same? This is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You mount your SD Card on different computer. All what you describe is as expected. It depends on how the SD Card is connected to the computer [1]. On your Ubuntu it is connected with an USB card reader. With this it enumerates device names just as they are connected beginning with `/dev/sda`, e.g. for your mounted hard disk, `/dev/sdb` for your CD drive and `/dev/sdc` for your SD Card because it was connected at last. On your raspberry pi it is connected into its slot. For this there is used a special device naming `/dev/mmcblk0`. For details look at the reference.

**references:**
[1] https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x99.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suffered from creating a new partition. If we didn't name the label of the new partition (not labeled), it would displays UUID. So I created the label of the partition and also I modified /etc/fstab because whenever I boot my raspberry pi, it replace the mount point to UUID automatically. Anyway I solved those problems and thank you so much.

Comment: Btw. with creating new partitions on SD Card have an attention that you do not run into the problem with [PARTUUID on images](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78291/79866).