# My RPi 3 doesn't boot up to desktop

Tags: raspbian-stretch, boot-issues

I tried running `sudo fdisk -l`, but I get

sudo: unable to resolve host (none): Connection refused
   fdisk: cannot open /proc/partitions: No such file of directory found

I also tried running `mount` and I get

```
mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? The microSD works fine, I have used it on multiple devices, and tried fresh OS installs but it won't boot up.
I have a RPI 3

To run those I put, `init=/bin/sh` in `cmdline.txt`

Comment: The title of your questions is, "My RPi 3 doesn't boot up" ???

Comment: Yes that is the title

Comment: If it does not boot , what are you "reading"? Does SD green LED shows any activity ? Since you used SD on other devices – did you verify they you have bookable OS installed on it? I know that is a stupid question to ask - but as the old saying goes "it works better if you plug it in ( software) “  still applies here.

Comment: I should say, it wont boot to desktop

Comment: Ahhh! That's an entirely different thing you see. Booting comes first; once that process is finished, then the desktop environment is started.

Comment: I just turned it on and I just see the raspberry pi symbols.

Comment: If you boot into `init=/bin/sh` then there is only the shell running. No pseudo file systems from the kernel are mounted like `/proc`, `/dev` and `/sys`. Then of course you will not find anything from `/proc` like partitions or mount points. But this has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: If you flash the latest image from [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and that will not boot then you have a general problem with your hardware, maybe defected SD Card or RasPi or power supply or something like this.

Comment: just turned it on and I just see the raspberry pi symbols. Same question - what are you connected to ? ( If it did not finnish booting AT AL ....)

Comment: @Ingo Yes I realize that by booting into init=/bin/sh is only shell, I was trying to see what the problem was by myself so I couldn't figure it out and that's why I'm here, and as I mentioned on the post the SD Card works perfectly fine on other devices. I just have a feeling the Pi is not detecting the partition? Since running "mount" and there isn't anything. The PSU works fine as well, tested with other devices.

Comment: @JanHus What do you mean what am I connected to? As in I'm running an HDMI connection to a TV? The only things connected are HDMI, SD Card, Keyboard, and PSU.

Comment: @trixonet what is PSU?

Comment: Could you please show us the mount command you used and the messages you got back? Thank you.

Comment: @NomadMaker `mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory`

Comment: you say you've re-installed raspbian. Are you saing that on fresh install, without any changes at all to the operating system, you get the same errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look step by step where the error could be. You are booting into a shell without any graphics. In the shell maybe you can mount the pseudo filesystems from the kernel (/proc, /dev, /sys). But it will not help you. There is nothing else. You can only edit config files.

You try to boot into the graphics system that is the systemd *graphical.target*. That get stuck. Next step before is the *multi-user.target*. That is the system without graphics as you get it with *Raspbian Stretch Light*. Try to boot into this. If it works we have a running system *Stretch Light* and we know that the problem is the graphics part. You can boot into it by appending this to *cmdline.txt*:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

If it runs we know the problem is the graphic system. You can enable journaling so we may see error messages. Enable it with:

```
rpi: ~# sudo mkdir -p /var/log/journal
rpi: ~# sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
```

Now boot into the graphic system until it get stuck wait a little and poweroff. Boot into the *multi-user.target* and look at the boot messages from the boot before with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot=-1
```

If you cannot boot into *multi-user.target* then you can get the next step back with appending this to *cmdline.txt*:

```
systemd.unit=rescue.target
```

Here you have a basic system including system mounts. Next step back is by appending to *cmdline.txt*:

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

Here you have a bare system nearly to boot with *init=/bin/sh*. This should always do if you can boot with */bin/sh*.

**troubleshooting:**
from the infos in your comments: it is possible to boot into *multi-user.target* but with read only filesystem. *sudo* cannot resolve host because there is no network connection with name resolution and for local name resolution there is no entry `127.0.1.1 raspberrypi` (resp. your hostname) in the `/etc/hosts` I guess. Put it into `/etc/hosts` if not present.

On boot you get the error:

```
Timed out waiting for device dev/partuuid-fb3ed1c9\x2d01.device.
```

This shows that the device `PARTUUID=fb3ed1c9-01` cannot be found. Postfix `-01` shows it is the first partition, means the boot partition. It is possible that the partuuid has changed, for example by [using a partitioner on a Raspberry installation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78291/79866). I suggest to change the device names in *cmdline.txt* and in *etc/fstab*. Put the SD Card in the card reader of your pc, mount its partitions and in *cmdline.txt* change the root entry to:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
```

*etc/fstab* change to similar like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

If `mmcblk0` is not the right device name for your SD Card you can boot into *multi-user.target* and look in `/dev` what it is.

Comment: I tried enabling journaling, but I get the error `sudo: unable to revolve host (none): Connection refused.` `mkdir: cannot create directory /var/log/journal: Read-only file system`

Comment: I just tried booting with default cmdline.txt and get these https://imgur.com/a/eRw9waW

Comment: @trixonet I have updated my answer with a section troubleshooting.

Comment: where do I find the name in /dev? Also `127.0.1.1 raspberrypi` is on `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Nevermind, it started to work after a couple of reboots? I have successfully booted to desktop